# Scalar product is 0 in any triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

How can we prove that the following scalar product relation holds in any triangle?

$$\left [-\overrightarrow{AB}\tan B (\tan A +2\tan C)+\overrightarrow{AC}\tan C (\tan A+2\tan B)\right ]\cdot \left (\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{AC}\right )=0 $$

I strived a lot but I only get to some long relations that overcomed me.

Comment: Angle $A$ means angle $BAC$, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define $\vec u=\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\vec v=\overrightarrow{AC}$, $\alpha=\angle A$, $\beta=\angle B$, $\gamma=\angle C$. From the sine rule one gets $u/\sin(\alpha+\beta)=v/\sin\beta$ and $u/\sin\gamma=v/\sin(\alpha+\gamma)$, whence:
$$
\tan\beta={v\sin\alpha\over u-v\cos\alpha},
\quad
\tan\gamma={u\sin\alpha\over v-u\cos\alpha}.
$$
By substituting that into your expression one obtains:
$$
\begin{align}
&[-\vec u\tan\beta(\tan\alpha+2\tan\gamma)+\vec v\tan\gamma(\tan\alpha+2\tan\beta)](\vec u+\vec v)=
\\
&\\
&(-u^2-uv\cos\alpha)\tan\beta(\tan\alpha+2\tan\gamma)+
(v^2+uv\cos\alpha)\tan\gamma(\tan\alpha+2\tan\beta)=\\
&\\
&(-u^2-uv\cos\alpha){v\sin\alpha\over u-v\cos\alpha}\left(\tan\alpha+2{u\sin\alpha\over v-u\cos\alpha}\right)+\\
&(v^2+uv\cos\alpha){u\sin\alpha\over v-u\cos\alpha} \left(\tan\alpha+2{v\sin\alpha\over u-v\cos\alpha}\right)=\\
&\\
&uv\sin\alpha\left[-{u+v\cos\alpha\over u-v\cos\alpha}\left(\tan\alpha+2{u\sin\alpha\over v-u\cos\alpha}\right)+
{v+u\cos\alpha\over v-u\cos\alpha}\left(\tan\alpha+2{v\sin\alpha\over u-v\cos\alpha}\right)
\right]\\
&\\
&=uv\sin\alpha\tan\alpha\left(
{v+u\cos\alpha\over v-u\cos\alpha}-{u+v\cos\alpha\over u-v\cos\alpha}
\right)
+2uv\sin^2\alpha{v^2-u^2\over(u-v\cos\alpha)(v-u\cos\alpha)}
\\
&=0.\\
\end{align}
$$